# JSON ObjectMapper serializes and deserializes to different JSON objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I get a JSON like this:

```
{
  "contactPointId": "123",
  "testString": "41277082",
  "address": {
    "name1": "name1",
    "name2": "name2",
    "street": "street",
    "houseNumber": "123",
    "zipCode": "45567",
    "country": "276",
    "contactPerson": "Bernd",
    "phone1": "1239",
    "phone2": "456"
  }
}
```

i want to deserialize it into 3 Java Classes

ContactPoint, Contact, and Address

so after i Serialize them again the JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "contactPointId": "123",
  "testString": "41277082",
  "contact": {
    "name": "Bernd",
    "phone1": "1239",
    "phone2": "456"
  },
  "address": {
    "name1": "name1",
    "name2": "name2",
    "street": "street",
    "houseNumber": "123",
    "zipCode": "45567",
    "country": "276"
  }
}
```

My Java Classes look like this:

```
public class ContactPoint
{

   private String contactPointId;

   private String testString;

   private Address address;

   private Contact contact;

   public ContactPoint( String contactPointId, String testString, Address address, Contact contact )
   {
      this.contactPointId = contactPointId;
      this.testString = testString;
      this.address = address;
      this.contact = contact;
   }

   public ContactPoint()
   {
   }

   public String getContactPointId()
   {
      return contactPointId;
   }

   public void setContactPointId( String contactPointId )
   {
      this.contactPointId = contactPointId;
   }

   public String getTestString()
   {
      return testString;
   }

   public void setTestString( String testString )
   {
      this.testString = testString;
   }

   public Address getAddress()
   {
      return address;
   }

   public void setAddress( Address address )
   {
      this.address = address;
   }

   public Contact getContact()
   {
      return contact;
   }

   public void setContact( Contact contact )
   {
      this.contact = contact;
   }
}
```

```
public class Contact
{

   private String contactPerson;

   private String phone1;

   private String phone2;

   public String getContactPerson()
   {
      return contactPerson;
   }

   public void setContactPerson( String contactPerson )
   {
      this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
   }

   public String getPhone1()
   {
      return phone1;
   }

   public void setPhone1( String phone1 )
   {
      this.phone1 = phone1;
   }

   public String getPhone2()
   {
      return phone2;
   }

   public void setPhone2( String phone2 )
   {
      this.phone2 = phone2;
   }
}
```

```
public class Address
{

   private String name1;

   private String name2;

   private String street;

   private String houseNumber;

   private String zipCode;

   private String country;

   public String getName1()
   {
      return name1;
   }

   public void setName1( String name1 )
   {
      this.name1 = name1;
   }

   public String getName2()
   {
      return name2;
   }

   public void setName2( String name2 )
   {
      this.name2 = name2;
   }

   public String getStreet()
   {
      return street;
   }

   public void setStreet( String street )
   {
      this.street = street;
   }

   public String getHouseNumber()
   {
      return houseNumber;
   }

   public void setHouseNumber( String houseNumber )
   {
      this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
   }

   public String getZipCode()
   {
      return zipCode;
   }

   public void setZipCode( String zipCode )
   {
      this.zipCode = zipCode;
   }

   public String getCountry()
   {
      return country;
   }

   public void setCountry( String country )
   {
      this.country = country;
   }
}
```

I was hoping for an Annotation which tells the Objectmapper where to get the Informations for Contact.

Something like

```
   @JsonProperty("address.contact")
   private Contact contact;
```

I don't want to create a whole new Java class structure just to change those 3 fields.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: hi, maybe you need to implement custom serializer and de-serializer with jackson.

Comment: In your 2nd JSON, where `"name": "Bernd"` should come from?  Also note that your `Contact` class has a property named `contactPerson`, not `name`.